# Image Types for Active Buttons

Tags: autodesk-viewer

What is the recommend image type for a toolbar button?  I would like to have the toolbar button color change to the 'active' color when the associated panel is active. Similar to how the Model Browser button works.  I've tried png and svg without success as can be seen in the image below:

[image: SVG button with A]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional information to the Viewer Toolbar icons, they are made from a custom font format - [WOFF(Web Open Font Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) with my finding and just like the [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) and [Bootstrap Glyphicons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/). You can see some configs like below in the `style.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'forge-viewer-font';
  src: url('data:application/font-woff;base64string...') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="adsk-icon-"]:before,
[class*=" adsk-icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "forge-viewer-font" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  // .... other configs
}

.adsk-icon-arrow:before {
    content: "a";
}
```

The A character stands for the arrow icon of the viewer dolly tool:
[image]

Before creating the icons for web applications, you have to covert them into SVG format, then use some tools such as [Glyphs](http://glyphsapp.com/), [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/), and etc. to convert icons into WOFF format. Afterward, create CSS styles for icon configs showing as the above. To simplify the workflow, I personally prefer to use the [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/) to create my own icons, it will create all required files (e.g. WOFF, CSS, ..., and so on) automatically while clicking "Generate Fonts".

Hope it helps~

Comment: Exactly the information I needed.  Thank you @eason-kang

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Autodesk is using a custom font library. Will look into generating a custom font library as well.

Comment: Just wanted to mention this. Good you found out yourself. Hope it works out!