# How Do the Buttons on the Toolbar Become Active?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I added 3 buttons to my toolbar like this (used example from a forge tutorial):

```
export class Edit2DExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {

    edit2DExtension;
    edit2DTools;
    edit2DContext;
    edit2DLayer;

    currentTool: string = '';

    lineToolButton: Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button;
    polygonToolButton: Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button;
    editToolButton: Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button;

    activated: boolean = false;

    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this._group = null;
        this._button = null;

        this.viewer.addEventListener('extensionLoaded', this.extensionLoaded.bind(this));
    }


     extensionLoaded(event) {
        ...
    }


    onToolbarCreated() {
       
        // Create a new toolbar group if it doesn't exist
        this._group = this.viewer.toolbar.getControl('Edit2DToolbar');
        if (!this._group) {
            this._group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('Edit2DToolbar');
            this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(this._group);
        }

        // Line tool button
        this.lineToolButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('Edit2_PolylineTool_default');
        this.lineToolButton.onClick = this.activateTool.bind(this, 'Edit2_PolylineTool_default');
        this.lineToolButton.setToolTip('Line Tool');
        this.lineToolButton.addClass('line-tool-button');
        this._group.addControl(this.lineToolButton);

        // Polygon tool button
        this.polygonToolButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('Edit2_PolygonTool_default');
        this.polygonToolButton.onClick = this.activateTool.bind(this, 'Edit2_PolygonTool_default');
        this.polygonToolButton.setToolTip('Polygon Tool');
        this.polygonToolButton.addClass('polygon-tool-button');
        this._group.addControl(this.polygonToolButton);

        // Polygon tool button
        this.editToolButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('Edit2_PolygonEditTool_default');
        this.editToolButton.onClick = this.activateTool.bind(this, 'Edit2_PolygonEditTool_default');
        this.editToolButton.setToolTip('Edit Tool');
        this.editToolButton.addClass('edit-tool-button');
        this._group.addControl(this.editToolButton);
    }


     activateTool(toolName: string) {

        this.deactivateCurrentButton()

        switch (toolName) {
            case 'Edit2_PolylineTool_default':
                this.currentTool = 'Edit2_PolylineTool_default';
                
                break;
            case 'Edit2_PolygonTool_default':
                this.currentTool = 'Edit2_PolygonTool_default';

                break;
            case 'Edit2_PolygonEditTool_default':
                this.currentTool = 'Edit2_PolygonEditTool_default';
                break;
        }

        this.startTool(this.currentTool, this.viewer);
    }


    startTool(toolName: string, viewer) {
        let toolController = viewer.toolController;

        // Deactivate active tool
        toolController.deactivateTool(toolController.getActiveTool().getName());

        toolController.activateTool(toolName);
    }
```

When I click the new buttons, the Navigation Pan tool is still shown as active and selected, and my new buttons are not getting the css for an active button. The tool itself is switched and I can start drawing with the Edit2D library, but the toolbar just isn't updating its UI. Am I creating the buttons improperly, or am I missing something?

As you can see in the picture below, I have clicked the "line tool" that I added and am drawing with it, but the pan tool is still activated on the toolbar.

[image: As you can see in this picture...]

Edit:

I am using the button.setState() function but it doesn't change the svg color like the regular tools. Just shows the button shadow. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the button state by calling setState() method of button class in your call back event handler.
You can specify any one of below 'Button.State' member.

```
Button.State = {
  ACTIVE: 0,
  INACTIVE: 1,
  DISABLED: 2
};
```

If you want to keep the button in pressed state,'you can choose Button.State.ACTIVE'.
Of course, you need to switch back the button status at end of the command.

Comment: Yeah that worked, however it does the same as me just adding and removing the 'active class' which is what I was doing. This doesn't change the symbol color to the accent color, just shows the depressed button. Is there a way to change the icon (svg) color on click? I edited my post to reflect the behavior as it is now

Comment: There is similar query in SOF, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861376/image-types-for-active-buttons . Hope this will help you.